# Hibernate updating a single column

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am confused as to the stance Hibernate takes when it determines which column information to persist.  Some places I read online says it will only update dirty fields, some people say that it is also database dependant (ie. Using hibernate with Oracle 9 will persist all fields of an object, even if only 1 is dirty).

Is there a correct way to handle this if you only want column xxx to change?  Or should that simply be abstracted to a different table?  Lastly, is any of this affected whether you use `Session#get` or `Session#load`?

Comment: Session.get() returns null if the id doesn't exist, while Session.load() throws an exception. Otherwise, I think they behave in the same way.

Comment: Even in terms of bytecode modification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dynammic-update` Hibernate mapping attribute:

```
<class ... dynamic-update="true">
```

Source: [Hibernate – dynamic-update attribute example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example).

Comment: I saw that, but I was confused what the original point was of making fields dirty if it just persists everything anyways?